# How to remote debug unit tests starting them from the debugger

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mstest, remote-debugging

I need to remote debugging some unit tests starting them from my debugger. Even setting the debug properties to remote debugger and setting the application to MSTest with the rigth parameters when I start the execution the settings are ignored and the local MSTest is launched.

Any hint?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: To clarify, I want to run MSTest from the commandline at a remote machine and debug that execution at my own machine. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know this is not possible in VS2008. :(